# tikz pgfplots: basic named dots in coordinate system

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I know the following is a basic misunderstanding (headscratcher) on my part.  I just want to place a few named points into an existing graph.  The following is an excerpt:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot coordinates{(0,0)}; %% as expected
    \addplot coordinates{(0,5)}; %% as expected
    \addplot coordinates{(1,7)}; %% as expected

    %% all of the below draw at 0,0!
    \node[label={T1}] at (0.8,0.8) {T5}; %% puts T1 at 0,0
    \draw(0.3,0.3) circle (0.2); %% no effect
    \node[label={270:{(0.6,1)}}, circle, fill, inner sep=0.1pt] at (0.6,0.6) {T4};
    \node[draw] at (0.8,0.8) {T5};
    \draw(0.8,0.8) circle (0.4);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

as always, helps appreciated. this one will probably be a one-liner, but useful for others to look up, too.

/iaw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the key `axis cs` in your later plots (the one made using the `draw` keys). From section 4.17.1 of the manual

> pgfplots provides a new coordinate system for use inside of an axis, the “axis coordinate system”,
>   axis cs.
>   [...]
>   It can be used to draw any TikZ-graphics at axis coordinates

So, this code should work

```
  \documentclass{standalone}
  \usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
 \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
  \pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}

   \begin{tikzpicture}
     \begin{axis}
        \addplot coordinates{(0,0)}; %% as expected
        \addplot coordinates{(0,5)}; %% as expected
        \addplot coordinates{(1,7)}; %% as expected
         %% all of the below should now work
         \node[label={T1}] at (axis cs: 0.8,0.8) {T5}; %% puts T1 at 0,0
         \draw(axis cs: 0.3,0.3) circle [radius=0.2]; %% has effect
         \node[label={270:{(0.6,1)}}, circle, fill, inner sep=0.1pt] at (axis cs: 0.6,0.6) {T4};
        \node[draw] at (axis cs: 0.8,0.8) {T5};
         \draw( axis cs: 0.8,0.8) circle [radius=0.4];
     \end{axis}
     \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The above code produces this image: [image: Generated Image]

You might also want to specify the the length of your axis with `begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=10,ymin=0,ymax=3]`

Comment: This is done automatically in `pgfplots` version > 1.12

Comment: @percusse, what is done automatically? The correct coordinate axis being used inside the `\begin{axis} ... \end{axis}` block?

Comment: Automatically assuming `(axis cs: <x> , <y> )` if not given.

Comment: @percusse, Thanks! That's nice to know. I should update my version then.